# Is Suppes' Axiomatic Set Theory standard?

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation

I've read 'Axiomatic Set Theory' by Patrick Suppes, and one thing I've noticed throughout is that he seems to be obsessed with definitions, and he tries to allow for urelements. Is this standard for ZFC?

I thought in general when we say 'set' in ZFC we really mean 'pure set', and so avoid having to worry about individuals. In addition I've never seen such a fuss over definitions in any other mathematical book I've read, is this something I should get used to in Set Theory?

If this is not standard, can anyone direct me to a book similar to Suppes' which builds (from the axioms) all the usual set theoretical structures needed for other areas of mathematics that is?

Comment: Only a comment - if you forbid ur-elements, you are nor more allowed to use examples like : the set $\{ John, Jim \}$ ... unless you show how to "build up" e,g, $John$ starting from $\emptyset$.

Comment: What about the following definition of a urelement (Suppes) $(\exists x)(\forall y)(y\notin x\lor x=\emptyset)$. Since the definition in Suppes of the empty set $(\exists y)(\forall x)(x\notin y)$ does not negate existence of urelements (individuals as referred to by Suppes).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep in mind that Suppe's book was written in the late 1950s (from his lecture notes), so the style and nomenclature are indeed a bit archaic and at times even perhaps chaotic. The book is considered to be quite difficult, and many universities only use it at the graduate level. As per my current understanding, the heavy emphasis on definitions and terminology which you alluded to are indeed commonplace in the ZFC formulation, but not so much in the von Neumann construction (which the author mentions in passing). I have been working with "Axiomatic Set Theory" for years and still have not really completed it, so you are not the only one who finds it hard going. As to whether you really need it depends on your goal, I suppose. Mine is topology, and in this regard I think Suppes' approach, difficult though it seems, represents a a good adjunct.

Comment: I find your post interesting, but I wonder if it attempts to answer the questions? Can you suggest a book for Nethesis? This is a "reference request" question. Welcome to Math Stack, I think your experience will be valued in this community.

Comment: I would be happy to recommend two similar references for the OP. First would be Paul R. Halmos' classic "Naive Set Theory", a short but superb introductory text written in 1960. This book is definitely more conversational and accessible in tone than Suppes’, so its a lot easier to read. The other book is “Elements of Set Theory”, by Zehna and Johnson. It is considerably more modern in style than Suppes’ and Halmos’ books, but again covering much of the same material. I would rank it as intermediate in difficulty between the two books previously discussed.

Answer (score 4):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urelement#Urelements_in_set_theory):

The Zermelo set theory of 1908 included urelements. It was soon realized that in the context of this and closely related axiomatic set theories, the urelements were not needed because they can easily be modeled in a set theory without urelements. Thus standard expositions of the canonical axiomatic set theories ZF and ZFC do not mention urelements (For an exception, see Suppes).

Comment: Well that answers the first part, it isn't standard, can you direct me to a similar book which is?

Comment: I think a good introduction (though it may leave you unsatisfied if you would like to see more rigour in the statement of axioms) is Paul Halmos' Naive Set Theory. It does not treat ur-elements.

Comment: Mmm, I'm more looking for an axiomatic approach, thanks though

Comment: Paul Halmos' book is axiomatic; the axioms are stated in plain language (hence the prefix "Naive").

Comment: Jech, Hrbeck - Introduction to Set Theory is good as well as Enderton - Elements of Set Theory.

Comment: Thank you, I will give those a look